# Flexbox justify-content: space-around doesn't work

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to have three divs, one bigger and two smaller, that are centred on the page and have equal space between them.
I've tried using justify-content: space-around; for a div that contains the 3 previous divs, but it doesn't work.

Here's my html:

```css
.flex-wrapper {
display: flex;
}

html {
background-color: gray;
}

#footer {
background-color: hotpink;
text-align: center;
width: 100vw;
margin-top: auto;
}

body {
height: 100vh;
margin: 0;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

.div1 {
background-color: pink;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}

.div2 {
background-color: yellow;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
}

.div3 {
background-color: blue;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}

.home-divs {
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<body class="flex-wrapper">

<div class="home-divs flex-wrapper">
    <div class="div1 flex-wrapper">asdggfh</div>
    <div class="div2 flex-wrapper">adfasgfd</div>
    <div class="div3 flex-wrapper">adsfasgsthdf</div>
</div>
<footer id="footer" class="center">© August 2021</footer>

</body>
```

Comment: try `space-between` not `around` anyways you have to apply it to the children of flex and not to parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give a width value for your `.home-divs` because it fits sum of children elements width and do not get space. I gave `80%` as an example

```css
.flex-wrapper {
display: flex; 
}

html {
background-color: gray;
}

#footer {
background-color: hotpink;
text-align: center;
width: 100vw;
margin-top: auto;
}

body {
height: 100vh;
margin: 0;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

.div1 {
background-color: pink;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}

.div2 {
background-color: yellow;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
}

.div3 {
background-color: blue;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}

.home-divs {
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-around;
width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<body class="flex-wrapper">

<div class="home-divs flex-wrapper">
    <div class="div1 flex-wrapper">asdggfh</div>
    <div class="div2 flex-wrapper">adfasgfd</div>
    <div class="div3 flex-wrapper">adsfasgsthdf</div>
</div>
<footer id="footer" class="center">© August 2021</footer>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gap property on your flex-wrapper, exemple:

```css
.flex-wrapper {
display: flex;
gap: 20px;
}

html {
background-color: gray;
}

#footer {
background-color: hotpink;
text-align: center;
width: 100vw;
margin-top: auto;
}

body {
height: 100vh;
margin: 0;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

.div1 {
background-color: pink;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}

.div2 {
background-color: yellow;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
}

.div3 {
background-color: blue;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}

.home-divs {
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<body class="flex-wrapper">

<div class="home-divs flex-wrapper">
    <div class="div1 flex-wrapper">asdggfh</div>
    <div class="div2 flex-wrapper">adfasgfd</div>
    <div class="div3 flex-wrapper">adsfasgsthdf</div>
</div>
<footer id="footer" class="center">© August 2021</footer>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used your code and applied some changes to the CSS code. Changes are applied to **.flex-wrapper class** and **body** element in the code. Have a look at it.
I guess I got the same output as expected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body class="flex-wrapper">
    <div class="home-divs flex-wrapper">
        <div class="div1 flex-wrapper">asdggfh</div>
        <div class="div2 flex-wrapper">adfasgfd</div>
        <div class="div3 flex-wrapper">adsfasgsthdf</div>
    </div>
    <footer id="footer" class="center">© August 2021</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS file

```
.flex-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

html {
    background-color: gray;
}

#footer {
    background-color: hotpink;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100vw;
    margin-top: auto;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
}

.div1 {
    background-color: pink;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.div2 {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

.div3 {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.home-divs {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

This is the result I got.
[output img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1axeQ.png)